# Unable to hide image on collection view IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uicollectionview

I'm using collection view and I want to hide and unhide an image based on the scroll ending detection.  But I'm unable to hide the image. Also, I want to show the image just above my tabbar.
Also, how can I put my image always above the tabbar, or just below my any cell in collection view.

**My Code:**

```
@interface
UIImageView *arrow;
end

@implementation
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 arrow = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 320, 20, 20)];
        arrow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"about"];
    [collectionView insertSubview:arrow belowSubview:cell ];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        arrow.hidden=YES;
    }
}
end
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from calling `arrow.hidden=YES;` ?

Comment: I want to remove that image. expecting the same.

Comment: Which image, you are creating unknown amount of images, at least one per cell, more if you scroll back.

Comment: I'm just creating a single image, just above the tab bar controller. And the same to hide when scroll downs

Comment: That image is just an indication.

Comment: All I can see from the code is that you crate unknown amount of images, at least one per cell, please back up anything you say with relevant code. Best case scenario with this approach: you'd be able to hide the last added view.

Comment: Ohh, this is my condition  if (indexPath.row == 7) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not creating more than one UIImageView.

You can put break points at 1 and 2 to check if you are hiding the same UIImageView object.

1: arrow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"about"];

2: arrow.hidden=YES;